# StackOverFlow On GAE but not locallly

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine

```
    User user = OfyService.ofy().load().type(User.class).id(id).now();
    JSONObject jsonUser = new JSONObject();
    jsonUser.put("user_id", user.getUser_id());
    jsonUser.put("device_id", user.getDevice_id());
    jsonUser.put("email", user.getEmail());
    jsonUser.put("name", user.getName());
    jsonUser.put("push_token", user.getPush_token());
    jsonUser.put("user_pic", user.getUser_pic());
    jsonUser.put("userWishList", ObjectifyService.ofy().load().refs(user.getUserWishList()).values());
   return Response.status(200).entity((jsonUser.toString())).build();
```

this code works correctly on localhost but not after deploy , stackoverflow occurs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError 
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain.implies(ProtectionDomain.java:300) 
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:462) 
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:698) 
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:47) 
    at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:1167) 
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:281)
```

I am not sure why this appears, on localhost I debugged it and works correctly as it should be also I can't see any recursive call for this errors, maybe lib doing that indirectly.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The error seems to be caused by the `JSONObject` class, maybe it has some recursive internal calls and the Google App Engine has a (way too) limited stack? (Just a guess, as I'm not familiar with GAE)

Comment: yes apparently because I can't see any recursive call and it works locally

Answer (score 0):

If the same code produces different result (e.g.: StackOverflowError) on different environments you should have a look at the configuration of the JVM.

For instance the stack’s size might be different on different JVM's. You can increase the stack’s size, in order to allow a larger number of invocations. Depending on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) installed, the default thread stack size may equal to either 512KB, or 1MB. You can increase the thread stack size using the -Xss flag. This flag can be specified either via the project’s configuration, or via the command line.

Comment: the app is deployed on GAE and why this error is related to JSONObject?